# Cannot log in with Apple ID after performing password reset

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id, password

My wife forgot the password to her Apple ID account. Her Macbook Air (OS X Yosemite) restarted to install some updates. She has her user account set up through her Apple ID account.

Since she forgot the password she reset it from my laptop.

She can log in to iCloud and Apple ID with the new password, but cannot log in with the new password on the Air.

When she tries to log in she is greeted with this message:

> "This account uses an iCloud password to log in. If you need to change
>   the password, use another device to change it at appleid.apple.com."

Comment: @Tetsujin New in OS X Yosemite is the ability to use your iCloud Password to log in to OS X and unlock screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Its a choice, it is not forced onto you to use your apple id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with Apple support for a couple hours, booting into safe-mode, and re-installing the OS (at their behest) we ended up just going into recovery and using the "resetpassword" command from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone still needing help, this is what was done to fix this issue.

If you reset your iCloud email and password online that does not update your icloud account on your computer with the new email address.

You need to login to your iCloud account online and set your primary email back to the original one (your computer is still using this email) reset the password if you would like.
Now restart your computer and you should be able to log back in.
Once you are logged in, go back to iCloud website and change back to your new email.
Before you log off your computer go to Setting>iCloud and remove the old iCloud account and add the new iCloud account.

That should be all you need to do.
Now your computer is using the new email and you should be able to login using your new password.

Comment: This is the right answer. Using resetpassword from command line doesn't work when you need to log in with an icloud account/appleid.

Comment: @sdm350: Unless Apple changed the behavior since I had this issue, using the resetpassword from the command line worked. What MacGod suggested did not work for me due to the stored password on the laptop not being updated when it was reset online.

Comment: Strange.... resetpassword did not work for me. Though it sounds like we might have had slightly different problems. I was trying to change the email address associated with my apple id, and my macbook was trying to login with the old email address (no longer associated). It also would not let me log out of the appleid after the old email was removed from the account.

Comment: "remove the old iCloud account and add the new iCloud account" is a bit vague - did you mean logout and login again? I ended up logging out of iCloud on the Mac, right after changing the Apple ID email address at https://appleid.apple.com - at this point I was prompted to set a local password for the account on the Mac (that was using iCloud account to login). Set this, and then logged back in with the Apple ID with the changed email address, all good. The key to getting back into the Mac though was using https://appleid.apple.com to change the email back to the original one first.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution for the situation when you've changed your AppleID and you can no longer login to your Mac:

If it's not possible to revert to the old AppleID because you no longer have that email address (in my case it was an old work email which got deactivated), then you can do the following:

1. Turn off Wi-Fi (I logged in with the Guest account and turned it off)
2. Login with your account (the login should be successful)
3. Change the settings on your Mac to prevent this from happening again (change the iCould account to be the new one, and optionally start using a normal password instead of the iCloud account)

Comment: Brilliant! I did not have access to my original Apple ID email (my reason for changing it in the first place), but this method worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the Apple support? I once tried that when I forgot the password, and within minutes the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the below is right except that you don't need to restart your computer.

1. You need to login to your iCloud account online and set your primary email back to the original one (your computer is still using this email) reset the password if you would like.
2. Now restart your computer and you should be able to log back in.
3. Once you are logged in, go back to iCloud website and change back to your new email.
4. Before you log off your computer go to Setting>iCloud and remove the old iCloud account and add the new iCloud account.*